# How to use Eigen Tensors to create a 3D matrix, then access a specified layer

Tags: c++, eigen

I've been using Eigen to translate some Matlab code, of course Matlab supports 3D matrices and I just found out that Eigen also supports Tensors now.

My question is, how do I use this feature?
Does anyone have a bit of sample code where a X x Y x Z 3D matrix is created, then a particular matrix within accessed?
My apologies for not providing any sample code, the sample code is what I am actually after here...

Comment: [This feature is documented](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html), which part is unclear to you?